# MySQL-Count the number of data based on a column whose type is text field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which uses data in another table.

**Table A** is basically the list of reasons for which the student's application can be rejected. If "Other" is selected, then there may be a text(optional, and from html side).

**Table A**

```
id            reasondesc                         flag
=========================================================
1               no documents                       0
2               payment not received               0
3               information mismatch               0
4                other                             0
```

Now, in **table B**, the `rejection_reason` column can contain one or more than one id from **table A**

**Table B**

```
id2                    student_name                         rejection_reason
=============================================================================
st1                        Harvey                                  1,2,3
st2                         KAcey                                     2,4,Failed to appear for admission
st3                         Tim                                      3,4,1,Did not bring his guardians
st4                          Abigaile                                 1,2,4,very unruly
st5                          Mike                                      2,3
st6                           Alex                                     1,4,2,did not perform well
```

Now, I want to count the number of data (individually) where the `rejection_reason` contains 1,2,3 and 4 .

Since the column is a text type, how do I do it?

Comment: Use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

Comment: 1,2,3 and 4 are all possible reasons. So what you want is to count all the rows of Table B. Or not?

Comment: None of your students have all 4 rejection reasons.